# Jointly training custom model with Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am trying to use [Tensorflow object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) models in another custom model I built (in the same codebase). Specifically, I am trying to figure out how below can be handled (mutually exclusive points):

- jointly train Tensorflow object detection model Y with another Custom auto-encoder model X - Possibility 1
- or just train custom auto-encoder model X while obtaining object detection Y predictions and incorporating it into X - Possibility 2
- or object detection Y input is (a tensor) from another custom auto-encoder X's intermediate layer (not a tfrecord or RGB image) - Possibility 3
- please note the above image shows only one architectural variation (Possibility 3). Essentially, if I can figure out how to do joint training with Tensorflow object detection API, I can do them all.

I have gone through the official TF object detection API [docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) and scoured the net trying to find good examples where TF object detection API was customized for cases beyond just object detection. I haven't found any. Any help or links would be appreciated.

p.s.: some relevant points

1. FYI, I can run/train Tensorflow OD API independently
2. Stackoverflow thrives on "show-me-what-you-did" culture, but as this question is preliminary and something that I haven't found an answer to in their documentation or on the web, hence shaking the community to find if someone has some thoughts on this.
3. I had posted a similar question on [datascience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/42854/using-tensorflow-object-detection-in-another-model) a few days back but no response.
4. TF object detection API github [new issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/new) encourages posting to stackoverflow for help and support.

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do with the second model? you are detecting the objects and than what are you trying to do with them at model X?

Comment: I think I didn't understand your point correctly. But can't you just train your Y model at first and when training has done, then feed your train data to your Y model and use it's output as an input of your X model and train your X model?

Comment: @Mark.F I have added a high-level architectural image of what I am trying to accomplish. The second mode is a auto-encoder. I want to train both models jointly.

Comment: @pooyan I understand I can do dis-joint training but I want to try joint training. My issue is more tensorflow implementation. how to modify tensorflow object detection API (which seems to use json config based approach) to do joint training.

Comment: I've not worked with TF object-detection API but wouldn't adding the appropriate losses for classification and decoder network and using it for gradient back-propagation work? Or is your question about implementing this using TF object-detection API? A JSON config will need appropriate connections between 2 models and addition of losses from 2 outputs in the loss part.

Comment: @KrnTneJa yes my question is about implementation. how the json config would fit into all this. if you look at TF object-detection API, https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md provides some clues on implementation but wanted to ask the opinion of other expert users.

Comment: I used disjointed training with TF object detection API for an OCR use case.

Comment: @JodhSingh can you post your approch as an answer?

Comment: All, I couldn't get this done using Tensorflow object detection API's they are not flexible enough to do such stuff. I ended up writing my own models in pure tensorflow.